# Thread safety and method arguments

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class `Helper` with one single method `int findBiggestNumber(int [] array)` and no instance variables.

If I make an object `Helper h = new Helper();` and let 10 different threads use that object's only method `findBiggestNumber` to find their array's biggest number,  will they interfere with each other? 
My fear is that for example thread-1 starts calculating its array's biggest number when the parameter in `findBiggestNumber` is referencing an array in for example thread-8. Could that happen in my example?

Comment: they will not interfere with each other, each thread will have their own `array` variable

Comment: Does you class any fields that are accessed from this method?

Comment: Variables that are in the method's scope, are exactly that. If there are no shared variables then it's perfectly threadsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the problem you described could not happen. As your Helper class has no members, it is thread safe.

Thread safety issues arise when mutable (changeable) data is shared between multiple threads. However in your example, Helper does not contain any data (i.e. variables) that will be shared between multiple threads as each thread will pass their own data (int[] array) into Helper's findBiggestNumber() method.

Answer (score 0):

Without your implementation of `findBiggestNumber`, it's impossible to say if it is thread safe since you could be mutating the array passed as an argument. If that is true, and you pass the same array to multiple threads, then there is potentially a race condition; otherwise, it is thread safe.

`findBiggestNumber` could also be modifying global or static data which would also make it thread unsafe.

Comment: The same array is not passed to multiple threads. The array is not mutated either, it's just used to find the biggest number stored in it.